# Conditional Expectation of a random variable given a function of another random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose we are given any three random variables $X,Y,Z$, such that $\mathbb{E}[X]$ exists. Also consider some real-valued function of two variables $f$. Can we rigorously assert that

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[X|f(Y,Z)=a,Z=b]=\mathbb{E}[X|f(Y,b)=a,Z=b]\quad ?
\end{equation}

In other words, is it possible to fix the value of $Z$ inside the function $f$?

Initially this seemed reasonable to me, but after some thought, I am not sure anymore...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the conditions describe the same set of outcomes.

$\{\omega\in\Omega: f (Y(\omega), Z(\omega))=a~\wedge~Z(\omega)=b\} ~=~ \{\omega\in\Omega: f(Y(\omega), b)=a ~\land~ Z(\omega)=b\} $

Comment: This is exactly what I had in mind. However, how can we rigorously explain this in terms of the sigma-fields generated by the respective random variables we are conditioning on?

Comment: You are *not* conditioning on random variables.

Comment: Of course, but still, is it possible to state the result in more general terms, and, in particular, when the conditional expectation is expressed as a function of $\omega$? Thanks.

Comment: "is it possible to state the result in more general terms" Which result? If you want to consider conditionings by random variables, one will be by $(f(Y,Z),Z)$ and the other by... what?

Comment: I understand your point; this what I was thinking myself and this is why I asked this question. So, this "step" where we explicitly fix $Z$ to be $b$ inside $f$ is true because $Z$ is fixed at $b$ in the other condition. Nothing special here.

Now, the same would happen if we conditioned on $(f(Y,Z),Z)$ in the following sense: For each $\omega$, the conditional expectation would be a function of $(f(Y(\omega),Z(\omega)),Z(\omega))$ and, simply, $Z(\omega)$ would be fixed to the same value in "both places" in the resulting expression. I hope I make sense...